# How to run a one-line bash command with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: shortcut-keys, scripts

I just made a custom keyboard shortcut, which is to execute the following command :

```
if [[ `banshee --query-current-state | grep playing` ]]; then banshee --pause; else banshee --play; fi
```

While this works flawlessly in a terminal, when I try to run it via the shortcut I just made I get this error :

> Error while trying to run (if [[ `banshee --query-current-state | grep
>   playing` ]]; then banshee --pause; else banshee --play; fi) which is
>   linked to the key (XF86AudioPlay)

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Yes, it does. Why doesn't it look alright ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that your script is being run by Bash, since you're using Bash builtins. Try this:

```
bash -c 'if [[ `banshee --query-current-state | grep playing` ]]; then banshee --pause; else banshee --play; fi'
```