# Create Keyboard Shortcut for Single-Line Bash Command

Tags: command-line, bash, shortcut-keys

I want to run `cmus-remote --pause` when I press **F8** at anytime, in any window, in Ubuntu. I've tried creating a keyboard shortcut (**System** > **Preferences** > **Hardware** > **Keyboard Shortcuts**) with `bash -c 'cmus-remote --pause'` as the command. This doesn't work.

I got the above command from this Ask Ubuntu post: *[How to run a one-line bash command with a keyboard shortcut?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/211773/how-to-run-a-one-line-bash-command-with-a-keyboard-shortcut)*

What am I missing? What is the proper syntax to initiate a bash command? Preferably I'd like to run this command **without** having bash open a new terminal.

Comment: Did you try to make a `.sh` file and then run that?

Comment: Yes I tried that. The `.sh` files worked as ok when I ran `./pause-music.sh`. But when I changed the keyboard shortcut to point to the scripts, the keyboard commands did not do anything.